# NSLocalizedString breaks webpage URL in string using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a number of strings that have internet links embedded within them that worked fine until I applied NSLocalizedString to each of them for a localization in Spanish. Now the links in the strings are not recognized or operate as such in my app either for English (the base language) or Spanish.

I have been unable to determine why this is happening and haven't found any reference to this issue online. Is there some special formatting that I have to do to the URL part of my strings when using NSLocalizedString that I didn't have to when using NSString? I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone could offer with a solution to my issue?

Here is an example of one of my NSLocalizedStrings and its use in forming the contentString:

```
aboutContentText = NSLocalizedString(@"\"The Visitation\", by 1737, Jerónimo Ezquerra (1660-1737), http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jerónimo_Ezquerra_Visitation.jpg\n", @"aboutContentText-2nd Joyful Mystery");
contentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                 initWithString: aboutContentText attributes: contentAttributes2];
```

Comment: Easy: Don't localize the URLs. Post the problem code for a better solution .

Comment: Show code for how you obtain the strings, how they are manipulated or processed (if they are), and then how you attempt to use them as URLs.

Comment: @Zaph: Please see the code addition to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: @KenThomases: Please see the code addition to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: Putting a string that happens to contain a URL string into an attributed string won't necessarily automatically make it a clickable link. Is this being set as the content of a `UITextView`? Is the text view's `dataDetectorTypes` set to include `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`? Also, try logging `contentString` and show the result.

Comment: @KenThomases: Remember that all my links were working fine before I changed them from NSString to NSLocalizedString. The string is being set in a scrollable UITextView, and I have the Detection Links box checked for this Text View. I tried breaking the string up into two parts; the first part is the NSLocalizedString, which is used to create a NSMutableAttributed string (resultString). The second part was the URL string that is used to init a temporary NSMutableAttributedString (aString) that is then appended to the resultString. But the results were the same - no hot link.

Comment: I understand that that's the behavior you observed, but it doesn't make sense. Assuming the code and the .strings file are in good order, there should be no difference between a string literal and the same string loaded from the .strings file. So, we have to work on diagnosing the problem. Please show the output from logging `contentString`. Oh, and while you're at it, revert the code to not using `NSLocalizedString()`, verify that it works again, and log the `contentString` from that case, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't localize the URLs, localize only the text:

```
NSString *preamble = NSLocalizedString(@"\"The Visitation\", by 1737, Jerónimo Ezquerra (1660-1737)", @"preamble aboutContentText-2nd Joyful Mystery");
NSString *urlString = @"http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jerónimo_Ezquerra_Visitation.jpg";
NSString *aboutContentText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@\n", preamble, urlString];
NSLog(@"aboutContentText: %@", aboutContentText);
```

NSLog output:

```
aboutContentText: "The Visitation", by 1737, Jerónimo Ezquerra (1660-1737), http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jerónimo_Ezquerra_Visitation.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code changes, but after applying them they still do NOT produce a clickable hot link URL that I had before I changed from NSString to NSLocalizedString. As you can see from my example, aboutContentText is then used to create an NSMutableAttributedString that I call contentString. The contentString is then appended to resultString (another NSMutableAttributedString containing other attributed text content) using the appendAttributedString method. Again, all this worked fine before the NSString to NSLocalizedString change. Very perplexing and frustrating.

Comment: So your problem is not in the localization. That leaves `AttributedString` to be the culprit.

Comment: I discovered what the problem was: I did not have the Text View Selectable behavior checked, so the URL links weren't being recognized and showed as such. In a recent localization of my code, I invoked Autolayout, and created constraints in the text view. For some reason this activity must have turned off the checked Selectable behavior, as my previous code version worked just fine. Anyway the URL recognition and behavior is now working as before. Thanks to both Zaph and Ken Thomases for your attempts and the time spent to help me. They were greatly appreciated!